# I could not substituted JSON file object to "[]{}" structure JS Object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

**---'./setindex.json'-----**

```
{
    "property":[
        "second",
        "third",
        "fourth",
            *
            *
        "end"
       ]
}
```

This code is able to substitute JSON file object to JS object.

```
var setIndex = require('./setindex.json')
var actionFunction = {
    "first": this.firstAction.bind(this)
};
for(var i = 0; i < setIndex.property[i].length; i++){
    actionFunction[setIndex.property[i]] = this.setMultiActions.bind(this,number);
}
```

But, I don't know how to substitute JSON file object to `{}[]` type of JS object. How should I do inside `for` loop?

```
var setIndex = require('./setindex.json')
var actionFunction = {
    "first": this.firstAction.bind(this)
}[listNum];
for(var i = 0; i < setIndex.property[i].length; i++){
    actionFunction[setIndex.property[i]][listNum] = this.setMultiActions.bind(this, i);
}
```

Output result

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'first' of undefined
```

Comment: []{} is not a valid json.

Comment: What is `listnum` and what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you will then use the code? are you going to call `actionFunction...`?

Comment: I can solve this question for my self.
It is way that object ab{}[] is separated. at First, var  hoge1{}. and add some JSON objects. Next, var hoge2 = hoge1{}[].